# Session Seems to be lost when Button_Click event fired asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, events, session, click

I am coding an ASP.NET website with **C#** and **Entity** Framework.

I stored into a session a *Login* class I created.  The class contains information such as the NetID, the Roles available to the user, and the role the user selects to login as.

The problem I am encountering is that whenever I try to get the information that is stored in the session inside of a `Button_Click` event, it seems to not get the information.  I do not know if this is allowed. However, I also put the *Login* variable that contains the user information as public variable for any function inside the partial class to access and I still have the same problem accessing the information inside a `Button_Click` event.  When I get the Session information inside the `Page_Load` event, I am able to get the values that were placed inside that Session.

The following is the code of my program.

```
public partial class Private_HomePagePortal : System.Web.UI.Page
{

Login SysUser = new Login();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] Roles;

    SysUser.Ticket = Request.QueryString["casticket"];
    SysUser.GetNetID();

    if (SysUser.Authenticate(SysUser.NetID))
    {

        SysUser.GetRoles(SysUser.NetID);
        Roles = SysUser.Roles;

        CasOut.Text = "Welcome <b>" + SysUser.NetID + "</b>!  You are now Logged in!  " + "Please choose a role you would like to sign in as." + "<br>" + "<br>";

        foreach (string item in Roles)
        {
            if (item == "Admin")
            {
                Admin.Visible = true;
                Admin.CssClass = "btn btn-danger";
                AdminBreak.Text = "<br><br>";
            }
            if (item == "SuperAdmin")
            {
                SuperAdmin.Visible = true;
                SuperAdmin.CssClass = "btn btn-danger";
                SuperAdminBreak.Text = "<br><br>";
            }
            if (item == "Member")
            {
                Member.Visible = true;
                Member.CssClass = "btn btn-danger";
                MemberBreak.Text = "<br><br>";
            }
            if (item == "Convener")
            {
                Convener.Visible = true;
                Convener.CssClass = "btn btn-danger";
                ConvenerBreak.Text = "<br><br>";
            }
            if (item == "ITAdmin")
            {
                ITAdmin.Visible = true;
                ITAdmin.CssClass = "btn btn-danger";
            }
        }
       else
        CasOut.Text = "You are not in the IUCommittee System!!!!  If you believe this is an error, contact the IT Administrator for assistance.";

    Session["Login"] = SysUser;
    Login User = (Login)Session["Login"];                           //Used to test information is actually in the Session
    CasOut.Text = User.NetID;
}

    protected void Admin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Login User = (Login)Session["Login"];
    User.SelectedRole = "Admin";
    CasOut.Text = User.NetID + User.SelectedRole;
    Session["Login"] = User;
}
}
```

I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: `Page_Load` code will be executed when you hit the button and in that case `QueryString` value will be erased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Page_Load` code will be executed each time when you press the button and in that case value  of `QueryString` value will be erased.

Be ensure that code in page_load gets executed once per page postback (use `IsPostBack`) or something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(Session["Login"]==null)
   {
     string[] Roles;
     ....
     CasOut.Text = User.NetID;
    }
}
```

OR

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
   {
     string[] Roles;
     ....
     CasOut.Text = User.NetID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was a simple thing, but at least now I know that page_load gets executed every time.  Well, I guess it makes sense thinking about it now.  Thanks again.